# Pyenv local version overrides all other Python versions regardless of 'global' or 'local' commands

Tags: python, terminal, python-venv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

Brief Background: macOS is Ventura 13.2.1 and the system's Python is version 3.11.2.

If I type `pyenv versions` in my terminal, I get

```
  system
* 3.9.16 (set by /Users/usersname/.python-version)
  3.10.10
```

I have no idea how `pyenv` set my Users folder with a local version of Python, but more troubling, this local version controls everything downstream from my Users folder because of its location. In essence, this local version is almost like a system version. Moreover, if I type `pyenv global system` or `pyenv global 3.10.10` and then check `pyenv versions`, I still get

```
  system
* 3.9.16 (set by /Users/usersname/.python-version)
  3.10.10
```

Yet if I type `pyenv global`, I'll get either the system's version or 3.10.10.How do fix this problem? Can I do one of the following?

1. Place myself in the correct directory (my Users folder) and then use `rm -r .python-version`.
2. Place myself in the correct directory and then use `pyenv local --unset`.
3. Some other `remove` or `unset` methods I obviously don't know about.

I found many tutorials on `pyenv` and how to set global and local versions, but nothing on how to unset (if that's possible) a local version. Is it possible?

Comment: I've heard several times that pyenv on macOS is a pain

Comment: I hope that’s not the case. Have you heard of or do you know about any solutions to my problem described above?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem per the following doc: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local

I simply had to place myself in the correct folder/directory and type `pyenv local --unset`, which removed the `.python-version` file.

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall for a similar problem. Whatever I did pyenv global did not change the python version. It turned out that I had issued a "pyenv shell" command which pegged the version whatever pyenv local or global commands I issued. So I issued the pyenv shell --unset command and all resumed working as expected. Thanks